# How to work on lists using recursion in Haskell and Java

Tags: java, haskell

I want to create a function in both Java and Haskell which will check a list for adjacent duplicates.
For example in Haskell the call

```
same[1,2,2,4]
```

would output `True` because two adjacent values in the list (the 2s) are equal.

How can I do this using recursion?

Comment: this is how i dd in the list comprehension same xs=or[che(x,y)|(x,y)<-zip xs (tail xs)]
che x y |x==y =True
              |otherwise =False

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: I have to guess at what you mean. My best guess: You have a list which you want to check. The function you want to use for checking is called `same` and it should output `True` if and only if there are two adjacent values in the list that are equal. Is that correct?

Comment: same [1,2,3,3] output will be true because adjacent values in the list is equal..

Comment: same xs=or[che(x,y)|(x,y)<-zip xs (tail xs)]
che x y |x==y =True
              |otherwise =False                                  i did the list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

```
same :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
same (x:y:zs) | x == y    = True
              | otherwise = same (y:zs)
same _                    = False
```

Comment: It's pattern-matching for a list with two elements (``x``and ``y``) and a tail (``zs``).

Comment: do u have any example like dis ?

Answer (score 1):

```
static boolean same(int[] a, int p) {
    if (p >= a.length - 1) return false;
    if (a[p] == a[p + 1]) return true;
    else return same(a, p + 1);
}

static boolean same(int[] a) { return same(a, 0); }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] tests = {
            {}, 
            {1}, 
            {1, 1}, 
            {1, 2}, 
            {1, 2, 2, 3}, 
            {1, 2, 3, 4}
    };

    for (int[] t : tests) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t) + " -> " + same(t));

}
```

---

```
[] -> false
[1] -> false
[1, 1] -> true
[1, 2] -> false
[1, 2, 2, 3] -> true
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> false
```

Comment: changing int[] to List<Integer> is left as an exercise.

Answer (score -1):

In Java that would look something like this:

```
public boolean same(List<Integer> list) {
    return internal_same(list, null);
}

private boolean internalSame(List<Integer> list, Integer last) {
    if(list.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if(list.get(0).equals(last)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        List<Integer> innerList = new LinkedList();
        for(int i=1; i<list.length(); i++) {
            innerList.add(list.get(i));
        }
        return internalSame(innerList, list.get(0));
    }
}
```

As you can see, Java isn't nearly as efficient in recursive programming as a language such as Haskell. The pattern matching feature used in the answer by uraf shows a powerful tool that Java just doesn't have.

Comment: You made this function take O(N) stack space (arguably this was necessary, since OP demanded a recursive solution) and O(N^2) time (totally unnecessary, why are you copying the list over and over?). Plus it breaks for lists whose first element is `null`.

Comment: @amalloy True, it could be considerably faster if I passed indexes rather than copying the list every time. My aim however was to make it somewhat like a solution in Haskell where you would only pass on part of the list.